# How to export classes in Guile Scheme using Goops?

Tags: oop, module, scheme, guile

In my project I have several goops classes defined in different modules (hence in different files). I can't understand how to correctly export a class (and its accessories) from a module.

This is what I tried. I also tried to export every time "slot-of-a" as I wondered in the comments but it doesn't work.

```
;;;module-a.scm
(define-module (module-a)
  #:use-module (oop goops)
  #:export (<class-a>)) ;Have I to export "slot-of-a" too?

(define-class <class-a> ()
  (slot-of-a #:accessor slot-of-a))


;;;module-b.scm
(define-module (module-b)
  #:use-module (oop goops)
  #:use-module (module-a)
  #:export (<class-b>)) ;Have I to export "slot-of-a" here too?

(define-class <class-b> (<class-a>))


;;;main.scm
(use-modules (oop goops) (module-b))
(define obj (make <class-b>))
(set! (slot-of-a obj) 'foo) ;This causes an error
```

However I find really awkward to have to export all the methods/slots/accessories separately, I would expect to be able to export an entire class .

Answer (score 0):

every created symbol-value binding needs to be exported, so yes it is a bit awkward to export all created accessors. But it is relatively easy to make custom macros that auto export accessors. Then in your example you need to re-export all symbols defined in a in order to get it from b. However I would just import from both a and b. It is also quite straightforward to re-export all exported symbols in a via a macro that executes in b.